# Converting database variables to Taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this in my code to convert either 0 or 1 to Successful or Unsuccessful.

```
$regstatus = array();
    $regstatus_compare = array(
        "0" => "Not Registered",
        "1" => "Registered"
    );

    foreach( $regstatus_compare as $key=>$value ):

        if( stripos( $row["registration_status"] , $key ) !== false ):

            $regstatus[] = $value;

        endif;

    endforeach;
```

Then this is the code that inserts it.

```
                $this->set_taxonomy( $post_id , "reg_status" , $regstatus );
            $this->set_taxonomy( $post_id , "response_successful" , $responsesuccess );
```

This is the set_taxonomy function

```
    function set_taxonomy( $post_id, $taxonomy, $post_terms ){

    wp_set_object_terms( $post_id , $post_terms , $taxonomy );
}
```

But I am still getting either 0 or 1 inserted into the website.
What am I doing wrong here?
This is a Wordpress site if it helps.

Comment: str_replace uses three arguements. This code should not run in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, your right it does not.

Comment: Fixed original code to reflect this.It still does not work unfortunately

Comment: Can you post the code which does the update ? And you should you check what value $row["registration_status"] is giving by printing it. may be that is where the problem lies.

Comment: Sure, I added the code to the original post.

Comment: I believe set_taxonomy is your own function. And it has an error. You should check

Comment: function set_taxonomy( $post_id, $taxonomy, $post_terms ){

  wp_set_object_terms( $post_id , $post_terms , $taxonomy );
 }

Comment: I updated the code with set_taxonomy function